# How can I search in Visual Studio for a a enum.value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, enums

I got this enum:

```
public enum Key
{Enter = 13, ...}
```

I'd like to search for any appearance of `Key.something` with `STRG + F` (in `Visual Studio`). The problem when I search for `"Key."`, I also get listed things like `"request.Key.Item1"` that I do not want. Can i restrict the search only looking for `Enums/Classes` called `"Key"`?

Kind regards

Comment: Right click -> Find all references

Comment: Can we say this question is related to Visual Studio and not C#. It should've been posted in software engineering.

Comment: @VineethChitteti Questions about Visual Studio are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

- Right-click the enum name and select `Find All References` or...
- With the cursor in the enum name, type `CTRL+K, R` or...
- With the cursor in the enum name, type `SHIFT+F12`

More details in the [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-references?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Diado is right.

If you don't use project references, and you actually want to search in a classical way, you could also use the Edit.FindinFiles (the combination Ctrl+Shift +F) and there search for Key.Enter with options Match case and Match whole word, this should reduce the "noise" of false results.